# Variables in properties

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<Me:FunctionalParFractal runat="server" ID="stockNextDayProg" MinZ=" I LIKE TO BUT it dynamicly" />
```

I know that I should do it from controller side but I ask, is this possible somehow?

Comment: Is _what_ possible? I have no idea what you're asking for.

Comment: what ever. How to set MinZ like MinZ="<%=var%>"

Comment: then that's what you should have shown in your sample!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to dynamicly set a proptery on a UserControl, you can do following

```
<Me:FunctionalParFractal MinZ="<%# MinZ %>" runat="server" ID="stockNextDayProg" />
```

And then make MinZ a public variable in your code behind, or data from your data control.

If you want to create MinZ in your Usercontrol, create a **property** in your codebehind.

```
public int MinZ { get; set; }
```